# Excel Formula to increment day by one except if it's a weekend

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

Basically what i want is for weekdays to increment by one every day but for weekends i want each day to display twice, so each weekday will have one row and each weekend will have two the current forula i have is

=A2 + IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2+1)={1,7}, AND(WEEKDAY(A2)={1,7}, NOT(WEEKDAY(A2)=ISDATE(A1, WEEKDAY(A1), 0)))), 0, 1)

But having trouble getting it to work.

The top row is a header row, then a static date for the start date then row three onwards should be the formula, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Example Column output: where 27th and 28th is the weekend

25-Jun-2020
26-Jun-2020
27-Jun-2020
27-Jun-2020
28-Jun-2020
28-Jun-2020
29-Jun-2020
30-Jun-2020
1-Jul-2020

Comment: Is your intention to have a column of dates / days like M T W Th F Sa Sa Su Su M T?

Comment: If possible input the desired data manually in Excel, screenshot it, then update your question with that screenshot so its clear to people trying to help you

Comment: Yes that's the idea

A1's Data is just text
A2's Data is 25/06/2020
A3's onwards is the formula

A2 onwards is also formatted as a Date

Don't currently have the ability to upload images, on my work laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=A2+IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<6,A2=A1),1,0)
```

Breaking it down:
Add something to the date above, but how much?

If the date above is a weekday (1-5 using return type 2 where Mon=1 and Sun=7)

OR

The row above was already a duplicate of the one before
Then - add 1, otherwise (row above is first instance of a weekend day), add 0

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

=WORKDAY.INTL(date,days,"pattern").. When you type the formula use
Syntax

WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, days, [weekend], [holidays])

The WORKDAY.INTL function syntax has the following arguments:

◾ Start_date    Required. The start date, truncated to integer.

◾ Days    Required. The number of workdays before or after the start_date. A positive value yields a future date; a negative value yields a past date; a zero value yields the start_date. Day-offset is truncated to an integer.

◾ Weekend    Optional. Indicates the days of the week that are weekend days and are not considered working days. Weekend is a weekend number or string that specifies when weekends occur.

Weekend number values indicate the following weekend days:

weekend-number

Weekend days

1 or omitted

Saturday, Sunday

2

Sunday, Monday

3

Monday, Tuesday

4

Tuesday, Wednesday

5

Wednesday, Thursday

6

Thursday, Friday

7

Friday, Saturday

11

Sunday only

12

Monday only

13

Tuesday only

14

Wednesday only

15

Thursday only

16

Friday only

17

Saturday only

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the syntax of that formula on its own will help the OP